# How can I use Kubernetes Python API to check health endpoints?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm seeking the answer regarding how to use the Kubernetes Python API to  check health

I am using:

```
kubectl get --raw='/readyz?verbose'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl get --raw='/readyz?verbose'` is probing the `/readyz` endpoint of the Kubernetes apiserver.

If you want to check the current running and ready state of a Pod and its containers, you can look at the Pod's `status.Conditions` and `status.ContainerStatuses` field.

If you want to probe the health endpoints of a container directly, you can use `kubectl proxy` or `kubectl port-forward` to open a proxy connection into the Pod's network namespace, then probe the health endpoint through that proxy.